# Send data from activity to fragment to update a list

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is the situation. I have an activity with 5 tabs (5 fragments). One of the fragments uses a `RecyclerView` to show a list of posts (like a forum). When users tap on an item menu, I need to implement the possibility of send a new post and update the list. I have no problems sending the new post to my DB and managing the response, but I don’t know how to, from the activity, tell the fragment to tell de adapter to update the list.  I hope I’m explaining myself (English is not my first language).

This is my code so far.

**The activity:**

```
public class UsuarioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public ViewPager mPager;
  public SlidingTabLayout mTabs;
  ...
  protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerUsuario);
    mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabsUsuario);
    ...
    mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mTabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab_view, R.id.tabText);
    mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    mTabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
  }

    class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public MyPagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
      fragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem (int position) {
      Fragment fragment = null;
      switch (position) {
        case TAB_INFO:
          fragment = FragmentUserInfo.getInstance(usuario);
          break;
        case TAB_COM:
          fragment = FragmentUserComment.getInstance(usuario);
          break;
        case TAB_SEG:
          fragment = FragmentUserSeg.getInstance(usuario);
          break;
        case TAB_IM:
          fragment = FragmentUserImages.getInstance(usuario);
          break;
        case TAB_FILES:
          fragment = FragmentUserFiles.getInstance(usuario);
          break;
      }
      return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle (int position) { ... }

    @Override
    public int getCount () { return TAB_COUNT; }
  }
}
```

The fragment:

```
...
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
...
public class FragmentUserComment extends Fragment {

  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  private RVIndexCommetAdapter indexCommetAdapter;
  private static final String KEY_USUARIO = "KEY_USUARIO";


  public static FragmentUserComment getInstance (Usuario usuario) {
    FragmentUserComment fragmentUserComment = new FragmentUserComment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong(KEY_USUARIO, idusuario);
    fragmentUserComment.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentUserComment;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    usuario = getArguments().getLong(KEY_USUARIO);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_comment, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.recViewUsuariosComment);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    indexCommetAdapter = new RVIndexCommetAdapter(getContext());
    indexCommetAdapter.setListaComentarios(usuario.list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(indexCommetAdapter);
}
```

I think it’s not necessary to copy here the adapter class since my main problem is how to send the new post data from the activity to the fragment.

PS: In case anyone suggests this to me, I know I could send the new post to my DB and managing the response directly in the fragment, not in the activity. In fact, that was my first try, but onOptionsItemSelected doesn’t catch the event of tapping the item menu and I lost enough time trying to solve it (reading lots of questions here included), so I tried this new approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the list from Activity you should make your Adapter static and call from your Activity notifyDataSetChanged(), it probably look like this

```
FragmentUserComment.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

To send data from Activity to Fragment you could make class with static variables and write them datas in your Activity and read them in Fragment. It's rather not the most professional method, but it works and it's very easy to implement.

Comment: But what I need is to send data FROM the Activity, not read it in the fragment, because is in the activity where I receive from my DB the data to be inserted in the list.

Comment: So where you want to send that data?

Comment: Ok, I should've explained the process. Summing up, when one user taps on the item menu to send a new post, a dialog is shown, the user writes his post and taps on send. Using volley I send his post to my DB. In `onResponse` volley method I manage the response and if it's ok I should update the list.

Answer (score 0):

create the method in the FragmentUserComment,look like this:

```
public void updateList(datas){
  mAdapter.setdatas(datas);
  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

you can call updateList() in activity when you refresh the list

```
((FragmentUserComment)fragment).updateList(datas);
```

Comment: That was what I thought at the begining, but the declaration of the fragment is inside `MyPagerAdapter`, so If I use your sentence I get the error `Cannot resolve symbol fragment`.

Comment: @DandyCC  can't declaration of the fragment inside .java separately?

Comment: sorry but I don't understand what exactly you are suggesting. Move `MyPagerAdapter` to a separate java class?

Comment: Move fragment to a separate java class